# Remove html elements leaving text content in PHP

Tags: php

Hi please any one give me a soloution for this. I want to remove the entire div and span from this html except 4 in `<span>`. Any one please

```
<div class=\"fivestar-widget-static fivestar-widget-static-vote fivestar-widget-static-5 clear-block\">
  <div class=\"star star-1 star-odd star-first\">
    <span class=\"on\">4</span>
  </div>
  <div class=\"star star-2 star-even\">
    <span class=\"on\"></span>
  </div>
  <div class=\"star star-3 star-odd\">
    <span class=\"on\"></span>
  </div>
  <div class=\"star star-4 star-even\">
    <span class=\"on\"></span>
  </div>
  <div class=\"star star-5 star-odd star-last\">
    <span class=\"off\"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

To strip HTML tags but leave their text content, you can just use `strip_tags`:

```
$string = "<div>Hello</div> <span>Hi</span> Other text";
$string = strip_tags($string);

// You'll probably also want to trim the results 
// to remove extraneous whitespace
$string = trim($string);
```

Which will result in `"Hello Hi Other text"`

PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @user1931956 - Cheers.  Enjoy!